# Flipkart app seach bar like transition

Tags: android, user-interface, transition

[image]

As we scroll down the serach icon in ActionBar starts appearing and It appears 100% when the search EditBox disappear.
How this transition can be created?

Comment: what was your effort?code?researches?

Comment: I am very new to android development and have very limited insight of it. So, first I needed a direction in which I can proceed further!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you, will ask the question in a better way next time!

Comment: `you can edit this one only`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html) that will help you out with this situation.

You need to create a custom layout first

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/searchfield"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:inputType="textFilter" >    
</EditText>
```

Than attach a listener to that editText

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    // add the custom view to the action bar
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_view);
    EditText search = (EditText) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.searchfield);
    search.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Search triggered",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return false;
  }
});
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
    | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
  }

}
```